# Disappearing Launcher Icons on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

[image: The screenshot] explains the problem. The first missing icon is for 'Screenshot' and the second one is for 'Sublime Text 2'. Can someone tell me what's going on here and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Specs: 12.04/x86_64/kernel3.4/Core2Duo/4500MHD

Comment: Do you have it when booting the original 3.2 kernel?

Comment: Yeah, it has happened when I was using 3.2 (which is no longer available on my machine).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing theme [System Settings -> Appearance -> Look -> Theme]

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with `missing desktop entries`.

To solve it , follow this link -[Creating Unity desktop entry -sublime text 2](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/)

Follow the steps from step 4(as i presume you have used the stable sublime text 2 ppa)